# unsatisfied authorization error while push transaction

Tags: eosjs

While using the push transaction I am getting the below error, Kindly help

{ "code": 500, "message": "Internal Service Error", "error": { "code": 3090003, "name": "unsatisfied_authorization", "what": "Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations", "details": [] } }

This is my smart contract code

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp> 
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp> 

using namespace eosio; 

class hello : public contract { 

public: 
    using contract::contract; 
    [[eosio::action]] void hi( name user ) {
        print( "Hello, ", name{user});
    }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH( hello, (hi))
```

Comment: It depends on what auth you have set in the smart contract code... can you provide the code? and the command you provide to push the action?

Comment: This is my smart contract code

#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class hello : public contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      [[eosio::action]]
      void hi( name user ) {
         print( "Hello, ", name{user});
      }
};
EOSIO_DISPATCH( hello, (hi))

I am sending body to the push transaction API

Answer (score 1):

Just import genesis account (eosio) keys in the wallet.
- Make sure wallet is unlocked

```
cleos wallet unlock
```

Now import the keys which are fixed

```
eosio public key: EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV
eosio private key: 5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDe
```

So your command of importing key will be

```
cleos wallet import --private-key 5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDe
```

All should be find after that.

Answer (score 0):

Import eosio keys to wallet and then try to push transaction

Answer (score 0):

Before doing `push_transaction`, there are few more steps to do

1. `abi_json_to_bin`- Convert the transaction into binary form(transaction packing)
2. `get_info`- To get the current block number
3. `get_block`- To get information about the latest block
4. `unlock_wallet` - Unlock your wallet(Make sure wallet is imported with required keys)
5. `get_required_keys`- Get the required keys from the wallet for signing the transaction
6. `sign_transaction`- Sign the transaction using data obtained from previous steps
7. `push_transaction`- Finally, push the signed transaction into blockchain

Make sure the wallet is imported with required keys. For detailed tutorial go to [EOS-Tutorials](https://github.com/EOSBlock/EOS-Tutorials/blob/master/EN/transfer-tokens-using-RPC.md)